# How can I get the index of the xargs "parallel processor"?

Tags: xargs, parallelism

Suppose I have two resources, named `0` and `1`, that can only be accessed exclusively.

Is there any way to recover the "index" of the "parallel processor" that `xargs` launches in order to use it as a free mutual exclusion service? E.g., consider the following parallelized computation:

```
$ echo {1..8} | xargs -d " " -P 2 -I {} echo "consuming task {}"
consuming task 1
consuming task 2
consuming task 3
consuming task 4
consuming task 5
consuming task 6
consuming task 7
consuming task 8
```

My question is whether there exists a magic word, say `index`, where the output would look like

```
$ echo {1..8} | xargs -d " " -P 2 -I {} echo "consuming task {} with resource index"
consuming task 1 with resource 0
consuming task 2 with resource 1
consuming task 3 with resource 1
consuming task 4 with resource 1
consuming task 5 with resource 0
consuming task 6 with resource 1
consuming task 7 with resource 0
consuming task 8 with resource 0
```

where the only guarantee is that there is only ever at most one process using resource `0` and same for `1`. Basically, I'd like to communicate this index down to the child process that would respect the rule to only use the resource it was told to.

Of course, it'd be preferable to extend this to more than two resources. Inspecting the docs, `xargs` probably can't do this. Is there a minimal equivalent solution? Using/cleaning files as fake locks is not preferable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're using [GNU xargs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html), there's `--process-slot-var`:

> `--process-slot-var`=*environment-variable-name*
>   Set the environment variable *environment-variable-name* to a unique
>   value in each running child process. Each value is a decimal integer.
>   Values are reused once child processes exit. This can be used in a
>   rudimentary load distribution scheme, for example.

So, for example:

```
~ echo {1..9} | xargs -n2 -P2 --process-slot-var=index sh -c 'echo "$index" "$@" "$$"' _
0 1 2 10475
1 3 4 10476
1 5 6 10477
0 7 8 10478
1 9 10479
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @muru's answer but note that the `_` at the end is very important! This is because `$@` only includes arguments `$1` and up after the argument to the `sh -c` command (because `$0` is the script name). If you don't have this you'll miss one in n of the inputs to xargs. Posting here because I was caught out by this.

Elsewhere I have seen GNU parallel mentioned which might handle this more easily without such gotchas. (posting as  a new answer because I don't have the karma to comment).

Comment: Please check the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get a handle on how these sites work. Answers are strictly reserved for answering questions, not for commenting. [Comments as answers will be deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).